# Gradient of $Z \mapsto \left( Z^T \left( \operatorname{diag}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T\right)Z\right)$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I know that

$$ \nabla_{Z} \operatorname{Tr} \left( Z^T A Z \right) = 2 A Z $$

and I would like to compute the gradient

$$ \nabla_{Z} \operatorname{Tr} \left( Z^T \left( \operatorname{diag}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T\right)Z\right)$$

I would like to see how this would be done, given my basic matrix calculus skills. All the entries are real and both $A$ and $\operatorname{diag}[(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T]$ are symmetric and $Z$ is a tall, rectangular matrix (more rows than columns), while $\operatorname{diag}(\cdot)$ denotes a diagonal matrix, whose diagonal elements are specified by the placeholder $\cdot$ and I think that $\left(\operatorname{diag}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T\right)$ is positive semidefinite (PSD), as it seems like it is in the form of a Laplacian matrix.

Comment: $\partial(\operatorname{tr}(Z^T A Z))/\partial X= (A+A^T)X$. Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Yes! It is symmetric. I'd mention that above. Can you go ahead with the derivative now..under the symmetric condition in the second problem where the $A$ part is a function of $Z$?

Comment: The derivative of the trace of $Z^T AZ$ can't possibly be $2AZ$. Trace is a real-valued operator whereas $2AZ$ is matrix-valued.

Comment: It surely can be a matrix. All the matrix trace derivatives in this link from berkeley have results that are matrices: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf and @Jacob also, concurs with this.

Comment: That document simply suppresses the vector notation. What they really mean is that $(d \mathrm{tr}(Z^T AZ)/dZ) E = \mathrm{vec}(E)^T \mathrm{vec}(2AZ)$. The key thing to take away is that if $f(x)$ is a map, then $f'(x)$ is a linear map such that $f'(x)dx$ is the same type of object as $f(x)$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong That's indeed funny. For real functions, we call derivative the number and not the linear form. Then in multivariable calculus, we call derivative the linear functional and gradient its representing vector. No surprise some people (not me!) take some liberty with that and call the gradient derivative.

Comment: @julien - But at least it's consistent in multivariable calculus, because a function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ admits a derivative which is an $m \times n$ matrix, which is how they are taught it. In this case, it's just really confusing because they unwrap a matrix into a column vector, but forget to mention that they do so.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I don't think it is really less consistent in this case. The identification $M_n(\mathbb{R})^*\simeq M_n(\mathbb{R})$ via trace representation is as natural, via the inner product $\mbox{Tr}(X^*Y)$. Just like $\mathbb{R}^{n*}$ is identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the Euclidean inner product. But you're right, it should be mentioned as it is less frequent.

Comment: Awaiting a solution!

Comment: I have it! I need to double check but I will post tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this. I like to use a variational approach in a case like this, since it's just sums and products. Well, there's the pesky diag term too, but we'll get to that last.

First, let's separate the additive terms:
$$\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z-Z^TZZ^TZ)$$
Now we substitute $\delta Z$ for each value of $Z$ present, creating a separate additive term each time. This is equivalent to substituting $Z\rightarrow Z+\delta Z$, subtracting any constant ($Z$ only) terms, and eliminating any higher-order terms in $\delta Z$. (This is not true in general, but when we have sums and products like this, it's fine.) The result is
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(
&Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(\delta ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z
+Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z\delta Z^T\mathbf{1})Z \\
&+\delta Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z
+Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) \delta Z \\
&-\delta Z^TZZ^TZ
-Z^T\delta ZZ^TZ
-Z^TZ\delta Z^TZ
-Z^TZZ^T\delta Z~).
\end{aligned}$$
Using the fact that $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(AB)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(BA)$ (when both products are well-posed) and $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(AB)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(B^TA^T)$, we can collect some common terms:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(\delta ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z) 
+\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z\delta Z^T\mathbf{1})Z) \\
&\qquad +\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(2\delta Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z-4\delta Z^TZZ^TZ).
\end{aligned}$$
That third trace is simple: its contribution to the gradient is, by inspection,
$$2\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z-4ZZ^TZ.$$
The first two terms will require a  term-by term slog. To do this, we set $\delta Z=e_ie_j^T$ to get the contribution to the $(i,j)$ term of the gradient.

For the first term, let's examine $\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(\delta ZZ^T\mathbf{1})$ with $\delta Z=e_ie_j^T$:
$$\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(e_ie_j^TZ^T\mathbf{1})
= \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(e_i(Z_{:j})^T\mathbf{1})=(Z_{:j}^T\mathbf{1})\cdot e_ie_i^T$$
where $Z_{:j}$ is the $j$th column of $Z$. Substituting back into the larger product,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(\delta ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z)&=
(Z_{:j}^T\mathbf{1})\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^Te_ie_i^TZ)\\
&=(Z_{:j}^T\mathbf{1})\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(e_i^TZZ^Te_i)=\|Z_{i:}\|_2^2(Z_{:j}^T\mathbf{1})
\end{aligned}$$
where $Z_{i:}$ is the $i$th row of $Z$. This is the contribution to the $(i,j)$th element of the gradient. Can we write this in a clean form for the entire matrix? I say we can. It's a rank-one dyad! The left vector consists of the squared row norms of $Z$, which are the diagonal elements of $ZZ^T$. The right vector depends only on the column sums of $Z$. So:
$$\mathop{\textrm{diag}^{*}}(ZZ^T)(\textbf{1}^TZ)=\mathop{\textrm{diag}^{*}}(ZZ^T)\textbf{1}^TZ.$$
where $\mathop{\textrm{diag}^{*}}$ really is the adjoint of the other diag operator: it extracts the diagonal of a square matrix and returns a column vector. The multiplications here are associative so I can drop those right-hand parentheses.

Now for that second term. First, we tackle the diag:
$$\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Ze_je_i^T\mathbf{1})
= \mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z_{:j}e_i^T\mathbf{1})=\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z_{:j}).$$
Substituting into the larger product,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^T\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z_{:j})Z)&=
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z_{:j})ZZ^T) = \sum_{k} Z_{kj}\|Z_{k:}\|_2^2.
\end{aligned}$$
Well. What does *this* look like when we assemble it for all $(i,j)$? Well, this is a matrix multiplication, actually, where $Z$ is the right-hand matrix and the left-hand matrix has constant columns with values $\|Z_{k:}\|_2^2$ in each column. So how about this:
$$\left(\mathbf{1}(\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(ZZ^T))^T\right)Z=\mathbf{1}(\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(ZZ^T))^TZ.$$
The symmetry with the first term offers some confirmation.

So assembling my subproblems, this is what I have:
$$\boxed{\mathop{\textrm{diag}^{*}}(ZZ^T)\textbf{1}^TZ+\textbf{1}(\mathop{\textrm{diag}^{*}}(ZZ^T))^TZ+2\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1})Z-4ZZ^TZ.}$$
I like the symmetry of this, and the presence of $Z$ on the right-hand side of each term. By George, I think we've got it.

But I'm sleepy. I'll check this in the morning, edit if I have to, delete if it's totally messed up.

ADDED: the quantity inside the original trace is not positive semidefinite, by the way, as the poster has guessed. Just try it with some random matrices, you'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the great answer

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
$Use the symbol $\odot$ to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product and a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \cr}$$
and define some auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign{
\o &&\big({\rm all\;ones\;vector}\big) \cr
J &= \o\o^T &\big({\rm all\;ones\;matrix}\big) \cr
X &= ZZ^T \quad&\big({\rm symmetric\;matrix}\big) \cr
}$$
Finally, here's a theorem about diagonal matrices and Hadamard products that's very useful.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Diag}(a)\,M\,{\rm Diag}(b) = M\odot ab^T \cr
}$$
Setting $\,\big(a = X\o,\; M=I,\; b=\o\big)\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Diag}(X\o) = {\rm Diag}(X\o)\,I\,{\rm Diag}(\o) = I\odot (X\o)\o^T = I\odot XJ \cr
\cr}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}\Big(ZZ^T\,\big({\rm Diag}(ZZ^T\o)-ZZ^T\big)\Big) \cr
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(X\,\big({\rm Diag}(X\o)-X\big)\Big) \cr
 &= X:{\rm Diag}(X\o)-X:X \cr
 &= X:(I\odot XJ)-X:X \cr
\cr
d\phi
 &= dX:(I\odot XJ) + X:(I\odot dX\,J) - 2X:dX \cr
 &= \Big((I\odot XJ) + (I\odot X)J - 2X\Big):dX \cr
 &= \Big((I\odot XJ) + (I\odot X)J - 2X\Big):2\,{\rm sym}(dZ\,Z^T) \cr
 &= 2\,{\rm sym}\Big((I\odot XJ) + (I\odot X)J - 2X\Big)\,Z:dZ \cr
 &= \Big(2I\odot XJ + (I\odot X)J + J(I\odot X) - 4X\Big)Z:dZ \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Z}
 &= \Big(2I\odot XJ + (I\odot X)J + J(I\odot X) - 4X\Big)Z \cr
}$$