# Find the derivative of a diagonal matrix and norm

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields, hadamard-product

Find the derivative with respect to $X \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times p} $ of $$ \Phi(X) = \operatorname{Tr} \left( X^{\top} H(X) X \right) $$ where $H(X) := D(X) A D(X)$, where $A$ is symmetric and $$D(X) =  \operatorname{diag} \left( (X_{1,:}X_{1,:}^T)^{-\frac12}, \cdots, X_{n,:}X_{n,:}^T)^{-\frac12} \right)$$ where $X_{1,:}$ are the rows of $X$.

---

It's observed that $D(X)$ are made from inverse of norm 2 of diagonal matrix $X X^T$. If $H(X)$ doesn't depend on $X$, I know the derivative, but it's not interesting in our case. In

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [Gradient of $Z \mapsto \left( Z^T \left( \operatorname{diag}(ZZ^T\mathbf{1}) - ZZ^T\right)Z\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/356475)

I have found a similar case where two elegant solutions were proposed, one includes using $\delta X= e_i e_j^T$ and the other used the Hadamard product properties( which I have no knowledge about it), but in the diagonal, they use a vector instead. While I have the diagonal of a matrix, which is like the $diag^*$ proposed in the first solution.

Comment: I need to double check my work, but the gradient is something like
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial X}
 &= 2\left(H-D^4\odot XX^T\right)X
}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
Y &= {XX^T} &\qiq dY = \LR{dX\;X^T+X\;dX^T} \equiv 2\,\sym{dX\:X^T} \\
B &= I\odot Y &\qiq dB = 2I\odot\sym{dX\:X^T} \;=\; 2I\odot\LR{dX\:X^T} \\
D &= B^{-1/2} &\qiq dD = -\tfrac12 D^3\:dB \;=\; -D^3\odot\LR{dX\:X^T} \\
H &= DAD &\qiq dH = {dD\;AD + DA\;dD} \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product $(:)$ which is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{C\odot A}:B &= C:\LR{A\odot B} \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the function,
then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\Phi &= H:Y \\
d\Phi &= H:dY + Y:dH \\
 &= H:2\,\sym{dX\:X^T} + {Y}:\LR{dD\:AD+DA\:dD} \\
 &= 2HX:dX + \LR{YDA+ADY}:dD \\
 &= 2HX:dX - \LR{YDA+ADY}:D^3\odot\LR{dX\:X^T} \\
 &= 2HX:dX - D^3\odot\LR{YDA+ADY}:\LR{dX\:X^T} \\
 &= 2HX:dX - 2D^3\odot{ADY}:\LR{dX\:X^T} \\
 &= 2HX:dX - 2\LR{D^3\odot{ADY}}X:dX \\
 &= 2\,\BR{H-D^3\odot{ADY}}X:dX \\
\grad{\Phi}{X}
 &= 2\LR{H-D^3\odot{ADXX^T}}X \\
}$$
My initial calculation neglected the $A$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a question abt the 7 th equality in $d\phi $, isn’t $sym(ADXX^T)$ instead of $ADXX^T$?

Comment: But the matrix is being multiplied (elementwise) by a diagonal matrix, so $\,D\odot{\rm sym}(M) = D\odot M = D\odot M^T\:$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Nice answer, as always.

Comment: We could simplify the formula even more  using the fact that a diagonal matrix can be gone to the other side :$2(H-D^2\odot{HY})X $

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer, I hope it helps you. Or perhaps someone can suggest how to complete it. I try to describe $\nabla \Phi (X)$, which is the matrix characterized by the equality
$$\dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial V} (X) = \nabla \Phi (X) : V.$$
We compute
$$\dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial V} (X) := \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \Phi(X + tV) \bigg|_{t=0}$$
as follows
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} & \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ (X + tV)^{\operatorname{T}} H(X+tV) (X + tV) \Big] \bigg|_{t=0} \\ & = \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ V^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) X + X^{\operatorname{T}} \Big( \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} H(X+tV) \big|_{t=0} \Big) X + X^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) V \Big] \\
  & = \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ V^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) X  + X^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) V \Big] +  \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ X^{\operatorname{T}} \Big( \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} H(X+tV) \big|_{t=0} \Big) X \Big] \\
  & = 2 X^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) : V +  \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ X^{\operatorname{T}} \, \tfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}(X) \, X \Big],
 \end{split}
\end{equation*} where we have used that the trace is linear and that $H(X)$ is symmetric (since it is a product of symmetric matrices).

Once we can find a matrix $M(X)$ for which
$$\operatorname{Tr} \Big[ X^{\operatorname{T}} \, \tfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}(X) \, X \Big] = \operatorname{Tr} \big[ M(X)V \big] = M(X)^{\operatorname{T}} : V,$$
we are done and we can conclude that
$$\nabla \Phi (X) = 2 X^{\operatorname{T}} H(X) + M(X)^{\operatorname{T}}.$$

Before that, it remains to understand the term
$$\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}(X) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} H(X+tV) \bigg|_{t=0}$$
and plug it into our expression.

To compute $\partial H/\partial V$ we first analyse $\partial D/\partial V$. Denote by $|X_{i}| = \sqrt{X_{i}X_{i}^{\operatorname{T}}}$ the Euclidean norm of the row $X_{i}$. Then
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial V}(X) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} D(X+tV) \bigg|_{t=0} & = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \left. \begin{bmatrix}
   |X_{1} + tV_{1}|^{-1} & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & \cdots & |X_{n} + tV_{n}|^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}\right|_{t=0} \\
  & =  \begin{bmatrix}
   -|X_{1}|^{-3} X_{1}V_{1}^{\operatorname{T}} & \cdots & 0 \\
   \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & \cdots & -|X_{n}|^{-3} X_{n}V_{n}^{\operatorname{T}}
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  & = (Y V^{T}) \odot I,
 \end{split}
\end{equation*} where $Y$ is the matrix with $i$-th row equal to $-|X_{i}|^{-3} X_{i}$. Hence, the derivative of $H$ is obtained by the product rule as
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}(X) & = \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial V}(X) A D(X) + D(X)A \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial V}(X) \\
  & = \big[ (Y V^{T}) \odot I \big] A D(X) + D(X)A \big[(Y V^{T}) \odot I\big].
 \end{split}
\end{equation*}

We just plug this in our expression for the directional derivative to obtain $\partial \Phi/\partial V$, but the problem remains to rewrite our expression in order to obtain the matrix $M(X)$ and consequently $\nabla \Phi(X)$. I am not sure the Hadamard product is the right way to go here, but I tried to use it since you mentioned; maybe some of its properties can be used to express $(Y V^{T}) \odot I$ differently, I don't know.

Explicitly, it remains to find $M(X)$ such that
$$\operatorname{Tr} \Big[ X^{\operatorname{T}} \, \Big( \big[(Y V^{T}) \odot I \big] A D(X) + D(X)A \big[(Y V^{T}) \odot I\big] \Big) \, X \Big] = \operatorname{Tr} \big[ M(X)V \big].$$

Or, not sure if it helps, the LHS is the same as
$$2 \cdot \operatorname{Tr} \Big[ X^{\operatorname{T}} \, \big[(Y V^{T}) \odot I \big]\, A \, D(X)  \, X \Big].$$

Comment: thanks for your answer, waiting if someone else could finish it, I don't oblige to use the hadamard product, I mention it since I have seen that it gives some results for similar work. Do you have any recommened book to read to see if I can continue your work.

Comment: I just found that the hadamard product commutes with the trace, $A:(B\odot C) = (A\odot B):C$, where the colod denotes the trace fucntion; using it, we can simplify the formula and extract $V$, it gived me, $M(X)=2Y^T [I \odot (XX^TD(X)A)]$, I should recheck this.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I couldn't check your formula for $M(X)$ carefully, but it does make sense. One thing to be careful is the order of multiplication of the matrices (it is OK inside the trace for square matrices). The property you mentioned is direct from the definition and I didn't notice, but I'm not really used to Hadamard products